# Ignore figure for list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I'd like to include some figures in my LaTeX document just like every other figure *but* don't have exactly these figures included in the list of figures.
Since I couldn't find a solution I have to ask you, is there a way?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204162/ignore-figure-for-list-of-figures?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As described in [figures in sidewaysfigure environment are not listed in List of Figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43824/figures-in-sidewaysfigure-environment-are-not-listed-in-list-of-figures/43825#43825) you can add an empty optional argument to `\caption` and load either of the packages `subfig`, `caption` or `subcaption` to make the figure not appear in the list of figures.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption[]{My caption 1}% Does not appear in LoF
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{My caption 2}% Appears in LoF
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of example]

Comment: If i do that, the figures are still listed in the List of Figure, only without their names, so there are empty references to the pages, which looks very ugly.

Comment: maybe it is also interesting to note here that non-empty square brackets will serve as alternative captions for the list of figures (e.g. if you want a shorthand version `\caption[LOF caption]{really long caption}`)

Answer (score 4):

taken from [texblog.org](https://texblog.org/2010/05/02/excluding-items-from-list-of-figures-list-of-tables/):

If the other solution does not work for you, use  the caption package as follows:

```
\usepackage{caption}
% ...
\captionsetup[figure]{list=no}
% now figures are excluded
\captionsetup[figure]{list=yes}
% now figures are included
```

you can toggle this as much as you like