# Large figure and legend on opposing pages in a two-sided book

Tags: floats, captions, double-sided

I have a 500 pages book with some figure and tables. Sometimes a figure needs to fill an entire page. The legend for this large figure is going to the previous or the next page. I wonder whether this could be automated in tex: When the figure is on an odd page, put the legend on the previous, even page; when the figure is going to an even page, put the legend on the next, odd page. So far I did this by changing the legend.

```
\documentclass[two-sided]{book}
 \usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-11]
  \begin{figure}[p]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.999\textheight]{example-image}% La
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}[b]
    \caption[Some rather long caption]{\lipsum*[2]}
  \end{figure}

  \lipsum[12-20]
\end{document}
```

The MWE is from David Carlisle from this question [full page figure with preciding caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205234/full-page-figure-with-preceding-caption?rq=1) and I had to change the position of the caption that caption and figure face each other.

Comment: You can add a test for the page number of the image and then set the other figure conditionally but I don't think that this is a really stable solution. If you move a rather large caption before the figure it perhaps don't fit and so can change the page breaking which means that it should go behind the figure and then you have a loop. Final Float placement always involves some manual work.