# Caption for multipage figure

Tags: captions

I am a novice and have started using latex for writing my dissertation. Some of my figures are long and might extend over to multiple pages. I need only a single caption and figure number(i.e. no sub-figure numbers). The thesis office however requires me to put the caption on the first page(Fig.xx Title), and on subsequent pages, I need to put Fig.xx Continued. How can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to put large figure caption on separate page from the figure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53315/5764)

Comment: How do you plan to split up a multipage figure?  Crop images into sections?  Anyway, the primary function of the \caption command is to number the figures.  If all you want to to write a caption, just write something (centered).  After the \caption you can use \thefigure to number it.  Before the \caption you will need to \stepcounter{figure} \thefigure \addtocounter{figure}{-1}.