# Separating figure caption scrreprt document class

Tags: floats, captions

I'm having problem in separating figure caption in `scrreprt` document class. I have tried using `\usepackage[CaptionAfterwards]{fltpage}` and an error message saying that fltpage.sty is not found showed up. I have also tried some of the methods given in [How do I make figure captions span multiple pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49858/how-do-i-make-figure-captions-span-multiple-pages) and [How to put large figure caption on separate page from the figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53315/how-to-put-large-figure-caption-on-separate-page-from-the-figure) but what I have tried returned no success. Is it because of the document class I'm using is incompatible with any of those packages? I'm working with overleaf.com online LATEX editor.

Comment: As it stands, with no example code and no error messages, we can't really help here. I've therefore closed as 'unclear' but will reopen if more detail can be given.