# How to put large figure caption on separate page from figure but not separated from the rest of the text?

Tags: floats, captions

I have a large figure and I would like to put the caption on the next page. When I use what I have found ["How to put large figure caption on separate page from the figure"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53315/how-to-put-large-figure-caption-on-separate-page-from-the-figure), it works with `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` because it generates a small figure but not when I use my actual figure. How do I keep text before the image and text after the caption on the next page?

Here is an example (I'm using sections to surround the figure with paragraphs of text):

(1) with `[demo]{graphicx}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{figure}[b]
  \centering 
  \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{figure.pdf}
  \caption{(Caption next page.)}
  \label{figurelabel}
\end{figure}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\begin{figure} [t!]
  \caption{(Previous page.) \lipsum[5-7]}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-4]

\section{Section 2}

\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

I get the caption on the next page not separated from the rest of the text, and the figure is on the previous page right before (no text in between), which is what I'm looking for:
[image: Result with demo-graphics]

(2) with my own figure (I screenshot a page and called it "figure.pdf"):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{figure}[b]
  \centering 
  \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{figure.pdf}
  \caption{(Caption next page.)}
  \label{figurelabel}
\end{figure}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\begin{figure} [t!]
  \caption{(Previous page.) \lipsum[5-7]}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-4]

\section{Section 2}

\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

I get the image and the caption isolated from the rest of the text:
[image: Result with my figure]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/figure-on-an-even-page-and-caption-on-the-following-page  Also, the limit on how large a bottom float can be is only abut 0.3\textheight.

Comment: John thank you! I've played around a lot with your proposition but I'm still stuck with 4 problems (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508973/figure-preceded-by-small-text-long-caption-on-next-page)

Comment: A large [b] float will not print until the next `\clearpage`  or `\end{document}`, and will be printed as [p] floats. To allow larger bottom floats, you need to increase `\bottomfraction` (macro).  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#39020

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.7}% one line patch

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{figure}[b]
  \centering 
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \caption{(Caption next page.)}
  \label{figurelabel}
\end{figure}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\begin{figure} [t]
  \caption{(Previous page.) \lipsum[5-7]}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-4]

\section{Section 2}

\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```