# Figure is as big as a page, and caption dissappears

Tags: floats, captions, size, figure-placement

I have a very large figure that consists of 8 smaller figures. I'm not using the subfigure package as I think for my needs it's easier to create the big figure in another program (GraphPad Prism). The problem is that the figure is as big as a page, and I cannot make it smaller as it would decrease readability. I have forced the position of the figure on a new page with [H], if I don't do this the figure is moved to the end of my document. The caption of the figure now dissappears, I suspect because it's too big. Ideally, I'd want the caption to appear on the next page. Is this possible? The code for the figure looks like this:

```
\newpage 
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{adjustbox}{varwidth=\textwidth, fbox, left}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Figures/Layout LDH CV 10k Fibro 3 days XY last two.png}
\end{adjustbox}
    \caption{Relative LDH release (absorbance at 490nm / max LDH release) and Crystal Violet (CV) staining (absorbance at 550nm) were measured for primary fibroblasts cultured in growth medium supplemented with either (A, B) 1 g/L glucose (Control), (C, D) no glucose or galactose (No Glu), (E, F) 0.25 g/L glucose (Low Glu), (G, H) 4.5 g/L glucose (High Glu), or (I, J) 1 g/L (5.55 mM) galactose (Gal). The negative control is shown with a dashed line in the CV assays (0.0725). Data is shown as $mean \pm SD, n=3$ for each substrate}
    \label{fig:XY LDH CV 10k fibro 3 days substrates last two}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: A figure [p] will take up to the entire text area.  Larger than than you need to overlap the margins.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508973/figure-preceded-by-small-text-long-caption-on-next-page,

Answer (score 1):

One option is split image in two parts and than use macro `\ContinuedFloat`:. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{figure}[!b]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=0.6\textheight]{example-image-a}%{Figures/Layout LDH CV 10k Fibro 3 days XY last two.png}
    \caption{Relative LDH release (absorbance at 490nm / max LDH release) and Crystal Violet (CV) staining (absorbance at 550nm) were measured for primary fibroblasts cultured in growth medium supplemented with either (A, B) 1 g/L glucose (Control), (C, D) no glucose or galactose (No Glu), (E, F) 0.25 g/L glucose (Low Glu), (G, H) 4.5 g/L glucose (High Glu), or (I, J) 1 g/L (5.55 mM) galactose (Gal). The negative control is shown with a dashed line in the CV assays (0.0725). Data is shown as $mean \pm SD, n=3$ for each substrate. (\emph{Continued on the next page})}
    \label{fig:XY LDH CV 10k fibro 3 days substrates last two}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!t]
\ContinuedFloat
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=0.6\textheight]{example-image-b}%{Figures/Layout LDH CV 10k Fibro 3 days XY last two.png}
    \caption{Continued from previous page}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate pages layout. In real document remove code lines, which produce them!)

Of course, you can  at second part of figure repeat complete caption text.

Comment: Since size of real figure is not know, for demo is added `height=0.6\textheight` option to `\includegraphics`.  When used real images, this option should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

We neither need nor want your image, but we do need to know how big it is.  Please run the following and report back.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\sbox0{\includegraphics{Figures/Layout LDH CV 10k Fibro 3 days XY last two.png}}%
width \the\wd0

height \the\ht0
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, this seem to be rather a comment than answer. However, this data is essential for helping OP