# Best way to separate figure and caption

Tags: floats, captions, subcaption

I have a large figure, containing several subfigures, which barely fits a page. The caption exceeds the limit and is "cut off" by the page.
I want to put the caption on the next page, but I have not found a nice way to do it.

My current solution involves `\captionof{figure}` after a `\clearpage` outside the actual figure, which results in the layout I want. However this messes up the numbering of my figures (probably since I am using the `subcaption`package), and I "skip", since it counts my figure and my caption as two figures.

Here is a dummy example of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple,font=bf,singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \caption{}
  \includegraphics[page=1,width=1.1\linewidth]{dummy.pdf}\\
  \label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \caption{}
  \includegraphics[page=1,width=1.1\linewidth]{dummy2}\\
  \label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\label{fig:dummyfig}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\captionof{figure}{blabla}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to either split the figure and caption, or reduce the figure count, so I am not "skipping" a number.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508849/how-to-put-large-figure-caption-on-separate-page-from-figure-but-not-separated-f/509079?r=SearchResults&s=9|21.4503#509079 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/figure-on-an-even-page-and-caption-on-the-following-page/281075?r=SearchResults&s=1|46.1932#281075

Comment: See also `continued float` from caption package.

Comment: Thank you. \addtocounter{figure}{-1} did the trick