# memoir - sidecaption ignore list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, memoir, sidecap

There is a method presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43995/ignore-figure-for-list-of-figures) on how to selectively ignore list of figures. Is there an equivalent method for sidecaptions in memoir?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}%This is necessary in order to ignore lof

\begin{document}
\listoffigures\clearpage

\begin{figure}
\begin{sidecaption}{Main caption}[fig:label]%unfortunately appears in lof
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Picture}
\end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Picture}
\caption[]{Main caption} %does not appear in lof
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are loading the `caption` package, you could use `\captiosetup{list=no}`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}%This is necessary in order to ignore lof

\begin{document}
\listoffigures\clearpage

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{list=no}
\begin{sidecaption}{Main Caption}[fig:label]%does not appear in lof
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Picture}
\end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Picture}
\caption[]{Main caption} %does not appear in lof
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But using `caption` with the `memoir` document class produces a warning:

```
Class memoir Warning: You are using the caption package with the memoir class. This may cause unexpected or inconsistent results if you use any of memoir's captioning facilities.
```

This warning indicates that since `caption` package is being used, `memoir`'s own caption configuration interface is not doing anything. If you want to keep `memoir`'s captioning facilities (without the `caption` package), I'd suggest another approach, simply locally changing the file extension used for the figure(s):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\nocaptioninlist{\renewcommand\ext@figure{ll}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures\clearpage

\begin{figure}
\nocaptioninlist
\begin{sidecaption}{Main Caption}[fig:label]%does not appear in lof
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Picture}
\end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\nocaptioninlist
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Picture}
\caption{Main caption} %does not appear in lof
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: The warning is just there to notify the user that when the `caption` package is used, then `memoirs` own caption configuration interface is not doing anything

Comment: @daleif yes; perhaps my description was not complete; I've corrected it now.

Comment: Thanks. Since I am using memoir caption stuff I used the second method. Where is the ll file then? Does the same thing apply for tables?

Comment: @rowman yes, you could say `\makeatletter
\newcommand\nocaptioninlist{\renewcommand\ext@figure{ll}\renewcommand\ext@table{ll}}
\makeatother` and now `\nocaptioninlist` will also suppress entries for selected table captions.

Comment: @rowman and to answer your question about the `.ll` file (which I initially overlooked), the file simply doesn't exist since nothing is creating such file.