# How to rename `\thefigure` only inside list of figure and remove some other of them?

Tags: captions

I use `caption` package and use figure inside theorem environment. Most of my theorem have only 1 figure but sometimes 1 of them has more figures. I usually renew `\thecaption` to renumber the figure such as (These figure have no captionname) [image]

In list of figure (right image), I want to remove figure `1.16b` (only inside list) and change thefigure `1.16a` to be `1.16` (delete a letter, only inside list). How should I do?

See my document below

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\textbf{\thetheorem}}
\setcounter{theorem}{15}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{\textbf{Figure}}

\begin{document}
\section{Figure}

\begin{theorem}
Some thing
\begin{figure}[h]
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\textbf{\thetheorem a}}
  \caption[a]{My caption 1}
\end{figure}
and something
\begin{figure}[h]
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\textbf{\thetheorem b}}
  \caption{My caption 2}
\end{figure} 

\end{theorem}


\begin{theorem}
Some thing
\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption[a]{My caption 3}% Does not appear in LoF
\end{figure}
and something
\end{theorem}
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Comment: I find this confusing. If you have sub figures, you should use the numbering as is and not introduce a different numbering scheme. And please provide a compilable document, not just fragments

Comment: redefining `\thefigure`  within the document is a very odd thing to do. Your question would be clearer if you showed some example input and described the desired numbering scheme,

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43995/ignore-figure-for-list-of-figures) looks like it might be of assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to stop using `\caption` altogether.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\textbf{\thetheorem}}
\setcounter{theorem}{15}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{\textbf{Figure}}

\begin{document}
\section{Figure}

\begin{theorem}
Some thing
\begin{figure}[h]
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\textbf{Figure \thetheorem a}: My caption 1}
  \addtocontents{lof}{\string\contentsline{figure}{\string\numberline {\string\textbf{\thetheorem}}%
    {\ignorespaces Alternate caption}}{\thepage}}
\end{figure}
and something
\begin{figure}[h]
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\textbf{Figure \thetheorem b}: My caption 2}
\end{figure} 

\end{theorem}


\begin{theorem}
Some thing
\begin{figure}[h]
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\textbf{Figure \thetheorem}: My caption 3}
  \addtocontents{lof}{\string\contentsline{figure}{\string\numberline {\string\textbf{\thetheorem}}{}}{\thepage}}% no caption
\end{figure}
and something
\end{theorem}
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```