# Manually adding content to list of figures

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, floats

So I'm supposed to make a command that manually applies label to a picture, using hypertarget and a counter, and then adds the one to list of figures. Note that the pictures I'm manipulating with, have to be included outside of figure environment, but rather in minipage. I've tried to manually put everything together, but it looks dull and not as the tex generates the list of contents. Here is the snippet of the code, any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcounter{x}

\listoffigures

\newcommand{\naziv}[1]

{
    \centering

    \vspace{2mm}

    \stepcounter{x}

    \hspace{15mm}

    \addcontentsline{lof}{section}{\arabic{x} \hspace{4mm} #1}

    \hypertarget{labela\arabic{x}}{Slika \arabic{x}.{#1}}
}

\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}

    \hspace{0.33\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.11]{slika1.pdf}
    \naziv{Pahuljica}

\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}

    \hspace{0.33\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.14]{slika2.pdf}
    \naziv{Trougao}

\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}

    \hspace{0.33\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{slika3.pdf}
    \naziv{Sestougao}

\end{minipage}
```

I hope it's not an issue that some of the words in there are not in english, it's just the names of the variables so to say anyway.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use \captionof{figure}{...} from the caption or capt-of packages?

Comment: BTW, Inside the minipage `\textwidth` changes to the minipage width.  I suspect that what you really want is `vspace*{\baselineskip}`. or `\null\newline`.

Comment: Well, my assignment is to kinda make it work manually, without floating elements, captions, figures, etc. I'm still familiarizing myself with LaTeX so it might be the only way to make this work, but if you have any idea I would appreciate

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372768/how-to-rename-thefigure-only-inside-list-of-figure-and-remove-some-other-of-t/372845?r=SearchResults&s=13|12.4719#372845 although this only works for single line captions.  The single line check puts the caption into a savebox and compares the width to \columnwidth, then uses either a \makebox or \parbox for the caption.